# What is best way to get canonical path from DistinguishedName in active directory c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

What is best way to get canonical path from DistinguishedName in active directory when retrieving all groups/users? is there any issue with following implementation

```
foreach (SearchResult entry in results)
            {

                var distinguishedName = entry.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString(); 
                entry.RefreshCache(new string[] { "canonicalName" });
                 var canonicalName = entry.Properties["canonicalName"][0].ToString();   


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You code will not work, as SearchResult does not contain RefreshCache method. The best way to convert DN to CN is to use [DsCrackNames](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdsapi.dscracknames) function.

You need to convert from DS_NAME_FORMAT.DS_FQDN_1779_NAME to DS_NAME_FORMAT.DS_CANONICAL_NAME.

Active Directory connection is not required to perform this conversion. You need to use DS_NAME_FLAGS.DS_NAME_FLAG_SYNTACTICAL_ONLY flag and then pass IntPtr.Zero as a connection handle

Be aware that foreign security principals cannot be converted using this function

However, if you already query DN, you can query CN as well. In your case the following code should work:

```
        foreach (SearchResult entry in results)
        {
            var distinguishedName = entry.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString(); 
            var canonicalName = entry.Properties["canonicalName"][0].ToString();   
        }
```

If entry does not contain CN, you need to add it to DirectorySearcher as a requested attribute before performing AD query