# How to split and join a DN to a path from an Active Directory object in either C# or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Using the following:

`string distinguishedName = deUser.Properties["distinguishedName"].Value.ToString();`

Dumped to a list is giving me the correct DN of a test user:

```
CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local
```

I want the output to read in the form of a path of where the object is located, such as:

```
testdomain.local/_users/PHL
```

I've done a search on stackoverflow and it returned quite a bit of old outdated posts using the method of only showing the parent OU, but nothing to a path.

How can I convert that DN above to a string path, not sure how to split and join it since I basically need the DN to be reversed from right to left with "/" in between to replace the commas.

I'm using the following in a list in C#.Net...

```
UsersList.Add(new UserAttributes
{

    Id = id++,
    FirstName = FirstName,
    MiddleInitial = MiddleInitial,
    LastName = LastName,
    SAMAccountName = samaccountName,
    description = Description,                             
    DistinguishedName = distinguishedName,
    email = email                                
});

return UsersList;
```

Any help in either javascript or C# would be greatly appreciated.  I'm using datatables so I can utilize a split and join using the "render" function in the column.

If someone can start in either javascript or c# with a simple string of

```
string distName = "CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local";
```

or a

```
var distName = "CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local";
```

and show me how to split, join, reverse it, I should be alright turning it into a function to use.

Comment: in Javasccript, use string split method, then arrays can use join method and reverse method to do as you require

Comment: what is the expected output for input `var distName = "CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local";`

Comment: Thanks all. If someone can do a code snippet, I’d like it to read: testdomain.local/_users/PHL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string test = "CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local";

        List<string> splitted = new List<string>(test.Split(','));

        int ouCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < splitted.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] split = splitted[i].Split('=');
            splitted[i] = split[1];
        
            if(split[0] == "OU")
            {
                ouCount++;
            }
        }

        string result = splitted[splitted.Count - 2] + "." + splitted[splitted.Count - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < ouCount; i++)
        {
             result += "/" + splitted[i + 1];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

For splitting you can use string.Split() function. You wrote that you want to reverse your list, but your given output exmaple doesn't match this.

Comment: Thank you Maitai, I put a similar comment above to Rahul for Javascript.  Yours worked as well for C#. But what if I don't know the amount of OUs there are? I only used the one above as an example. I'm assuming it might be a for loop looking for how many "OU"s there are. Example, it could be "CN=Test User, OU=Firewalls, OU=Network Devices, OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local". Some of my structure in my environment are 9 OUs deep. Thanks again

Comment: Split by comma won’t work if DN value contains comma, as it will be escaped and will look like CN=Test \, User, OU=…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40269546/6826115 converts object dn to cn

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.split()` to split by `comma (,)` and then format path output using the template literals.

```js
var distName = "CN=Test User,OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local";

const getValue = (input) => input.split("=").pop();

const formattedPath = (str) => {
  const list = str.split(",");
  const len = list.length;
  return `${getValue(list[len-2])}.${getValue(list[len-1])}/${getValue(list[len-3])}/${getValue(list[len-4])}`;
}

console.log(formattedPath(distName));
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, this worked amazingly in JavaScript.  One more thing, what if I don't know the amount of OUs there are?  I only used the one above as an example.  I'm assuming it might be a for loop looking for how many "OU"s there are.  Example, it could be "CN=Test User, OU=Firewalls, OU=Network Devices, OU=PHL,OU=_users,DC=testdomain,DC=local".

Some of my structure in my environment are 9 OUs deep.

Thanks again

Comment: @muttBunch, what would be expected output for above example?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LdapName classs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/LdapName.html)

It takes a ldap path as string and allows you to access elements by index and offers many other features. Some [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/ldapname.html).

Spring built on top of LdapName the [LdapNameBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/support/LdapNameBuilder.html)

Check it out